# Trying to get Raspian to play with my HiFi DAC

Tags: usb, audio

Complete beginner with Raspberry Pis, linux etc. Thought it would be a nice project to make up a 'media centre' to playback music files and movies from various sources, using my hifi system for better sound than the TV.
I bought the 'Media Centre Kit' from Pi Hut with no instructions, but assembled it and got it half-working. What's really peeing me off is that my Musical Fidelity DAC is recognised and works when using libreElec as the media player, but when using youtube on Chromium in Raspian the DAC appears when I right click the 'speaker' icon but can't be selected. I haven't worked out how to get a web browser up in libreElec to watch youtube on, or it wouldn't be so annoying. 
Any help welcome on any of the above!
Alex